# xml string in Parameter is partially passed to API

Tags: xml, rest, web-services, asp.net-web-api, parameter-passing

Facing trouble while passing the xml string as parameter in query string during web API Call. I Know its due to special character representation. But don't know how to solve it.
The xml string that I need to pass is:

```
<tagName name="red" query="tableName &lt;&gt; ''" requestId="requestorName:sessionID" />
```

but on service side only thing that gets passed is

```
<tagName name="red" query="tableName
```

since the passed string is documented as xml i can't replace &lt with < and &gt  with >.  Please provide me a solution.

I am attaching the string to client as follows:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/xml";
var param = new NameValueCollection();
param.Add("tagName", Content);   //Content contains the xml string to be passed
client.QueryString = param;
client.DownloadString("http://localhost:8000/api/method");
```

I have a web API as follows

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/getquery")]
public HttpResponseMessage method(string tagName)
{
  //funtions to perform
}
```

Web api catches the partial string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finding solution to my own queries.. :D

Actually what I didn't take into consideration was that when we add some parameters to query string the complete http request generates as follows.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/xml";
var param = new NameValueCollection();
param.Add("tagName", Content);   //Content contains the xml string to be passed
client.QueryString = param;
client.DownloadString("http://localhost:8000/api/method");
```

Suppose the Content has value "abcd", hence the http-request becomes:
"http://localhost:8000/api/method?tagName=abcd"

Now if add more parameters like

```
param.Add("tagValue", "ghij")
```

the request is
"http://localhost:8000/api/method?tagName=abcd&tagValue=ghij"

Since my parameter value contains the special character "&" what it does that it considers everything post that as another parameter whose value is not being matched. Key is use "Uri.EscapeDataString()" which actually tell the program to consider the "&" as part of the parameter value and not the query-string special character.

hence the proper code would be:

```
param.Add("tagName", Uri.EscapeDataString(Content));
```

Hope it helps others too.